# More than 5 years in the US, under OPT, can I use TurboTax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, f1-student-visa, turbotax

I have been in the US since January 2011 (I have been living here for 5 years and 2 months)-Technically, MORE than 5 years, I am currently working under OPT, can I use TurboTax to file my taxes? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the year 2015, you are a nonresident alien, because you are an exempt individual during your time in F1 status in 2015, because you hadn't been an exempt individual for some part of 5 calendar years before 2015. Since you are filing 2015 taxes now, you need to file as a nonresident alien, and I don't think TurboTax can do that.

For the year 2016 (whose taxes you will be doing this time next year), you will be a resident alien, because you had already been an exempt individual as a student for part of 5 previous calendar years (2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, and 2015), and you would be able to use TurboTax to file that (although there may or may not be treaty benefits still available to you which TurboTax may not be able to handle).